# How do I delete a row from Sqlite using ID where my ID is binary data (GUID)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, guid, sql-delete

So I have a Sqlite table `[Customers]` and a column `[CustomerId]` which is a `Guid` but as there is no `Guid` type in sqlite I have saved it as `binary` so I thought I could use the statement:

```
delete from [Customers] where [CustomerId] ='|����8B�����\�'
```

where `|����8B�����\�` is my binary representation in my Sqlite explorer, but this returns

> (0) Rows Affected

How can I delete a row based on my `Id` column which is effectively a `Guid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way of using binary data:

- use a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

  ```
  DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = x'1234AB...'
  ```
- use [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```py
    guid = ...
    sql = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = ?"
    db.execute(sql, [guid])
```